# How to Share existing ntfs partition to windows network with specific users

Tags: networking, permissions, hard-drive

Im a newbie in Ubuntu so I need all the help I can get. Here's my situation:

I have an hdd with 2 NTFS partitions: 1. Windows System & 2. Data
What I would like to accomplish is to put this hdd in an Ubuntu system and share the Data partition only with permissions given to select users. I've already set up an Ubuntu desktop, even tested basic network sharing (Nautilus) but I couldn't share an added hdd to the network. I can only effectively share folders in /home. I don't want to alter the structure/file system of the hdd because I want that hdd to boot up to it's original OS (windows) in its original PC if I need to . Tried samba but I couldn't set specific users and permissions. To sum it up:

1. I have an ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on a PC with 80GB hdd
2. I have an hdd from another PC with 2 Partitions c:\System, d:\data
3. I need to put the hdd to the ubuntu desktop and share d:\data in network
4. I need to limit access permissions on that share to select users (password protected)
5. If I have to, I need to be able to load that hdd back to its original PC and run its OS and use the d:\data partition as before

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Samba, but you have to:
1. Create Samba users (use smbpasswd command).
2. Then auto-mount (on etc/fstab) the d:/data device on startup. 
3. Finally, share the folder configuring a share on smb.conf and adding the users with permissions.

Hope it helps.